# How do I create an edge-list (relation between the nodes) from a node list and a second variable? For network analysis

Tags: r, dplyr, network-programming, tidyverse

I need to get an edge-list from a data frame that has the nodes in a column.

I have a list of authors of a certain proposition, but I want to get the network of the relation between them.

Will show an example:

I have this data frame:

| Proposition | Author |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 4 |

If there are authors to a same proposition, they all relate to each other. So the result I need is a data frame like this:

| Proposition | Author 1 (From) | Author 2 (To) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| A | 1 | 4 |
| A | 2 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 4 |
| A | 3 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 4 |

I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: Could you add your data in a format that's directly copy-pasteable into R?

Comment: proposition <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
author <- c(1,2,3,4,2,4)
df <- data.frame(proposition, author)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give what you're looking for:

```r
proposition <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B") 
author <- c(1,2,3,4,2,4) 
df <- data.frame(proposition, author)

library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  rename(from = author) |> 
  full_join(rename(df, to = author), by = "proposition") |> 
  filter(from < to)
#>   proposition from to
#> 1           A    1  2
#> 2           A    1  3
#> 3           A    1  4
#> 4           A    2  3
#> 5           A    2  4
#> 6           A    3  4
#> 7           B    2  4
```

Comment: Great! I'd you get a chance mark as closed :)